# Zsh '&> /dev/null &' alias?

Tags: bash, alias, zsh

I find myself appending `&> /dev/null &` all the time, so is there a way I can add it as an alias such as `bgh`, so I can just say something like `rails server bgh`?

I've tried using `global` and `suffix aliases`, but they don't seem to work for what I want.  In a case like `rails server &> /dev/null &`, what is actual terminology for the role of `&> /dev/null &`?  Is it considered a command option or argument?

Thanks

Comment: Are you opposed to `bgh rails server` instead of `rails server bgh`? (in other words, define a function which runs the rest of the command line as you describe it).

Comment: Nope, that would be completely fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
~$ bgh() { "$@" &>/dev/null & }
~$ jobs
~$ bgh sleep 2
[1] 5563
~$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 "$@" &>/dev/null &
~$ 
[1]+  Done                    "$@" &>/dev/null
```

Explicitly installing zsh & running it there does the same thing:

```
 ~ % bgh() { "$@" &>/dev/null & }    
 ~ % bgh sleep 1
[2] 6482
 ~ % 
[2]  + done       "$@" &> /dev/null
```

To get it POSIX compliant (the `&>` may not work in every shell), we can use this:

```
~$ bgh() { "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 & }
```

Comment: Thanks for the function!  But every time I enter in the bgh function I get: `zsh: parse error near '&' `

Comment: @user2736286, I can't reproduce that. Are you sure you're entering it **exactly** as it was given?

Comment: Hm, damn, I use bash here... Lemme install zsh & check ;)

Comment: ...to be clear, I tested, and found it to work, against zsh 5.0.5.

Comment: ...if you were running zsh in a POSIX compatibility mode, that might break it -- `&>` isn't POSIX-compliant. (Though if you wanted POSIX compliance, why you'd use zsh...)

Comment: Can't reproduces the problem either. Perhaps a quoting issue, what are you running _exactly_?

Comment: I am copy pasting `bgh() { "$@" &>/dev/null & }` into iterm 2 running zsh.  I'll check with bash real quick, but sorry I have to run real quick and will be back in a couple of hours to check the thread.  Thanks so much for your help.  If it works for everyone else, good enough!

Comment: Ok works perfectly with bash, so must be a problem with my zsh shell.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm. zsh has a lot of compatibility-impacting knobs that can be twiddled, so it's hard to say how that problem is coming about without knowing exact version and everything going into its configuration. If you wanted to make that a pure POSIX script, all you'd need to do to change it would be to make it `bgh() { "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 & }` and any shell which couldn't run it would actually be out-of-spec w/ POSIX. (Which actually may or may not matter to zsh, which doesn't even try to be a POSIX superset unless it's running in a non-default mode).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: yep, you got a point there, there is no need to use a keystroke-saving feature that may or may not be there, if it's just hiding in a function that only needs to be typed _once_. I'll edit it.

Comment: Ok, found the problem.  I forgot to delete the old bgh alias I had in my .zshrc when I was experimenting: `alias bgh='&> /dev/null &'`.  Sorry guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed do that with an alias in zsh:

```
alias -g bgh='&> /dev/null &'
```

and test

```
$ man zsh bgh
[1] 18863
$
[1]  + done       man zsh &> /dev/null
```

Even though I would personally not include the background & into the alias.